# How to remove entering special characters while i'm typing? (Angular)

Tags: angular

How can I remove special characters while I'm typing in the input field. I used (keyup) or (keydown) and replace for this. I attached the code. I will appreciate any help. Thanks!

```js
removeSpecialCharacters(event) {
    let newVal = event.target.value.replace('[^A-Za-z0-9]', '');
    return newVal;
  }
```

```html
<input maxlength="10" (keydown)="this.removeSpecialCharacters($event)">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can use this Directive**

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[specialIsAlphaNumeric]'
})
export class SpecialCharacterDirective {

  regexStr = '^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$';
  @Input() isAlphaNumeric: boolean;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }


  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) onKeyPress(event) {
    return new RegExp(this.regexStr).test(event.key);
  }

  @HostListener('paste', ['$event']) blockPaste(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.validateFields(event);
  }

  validateFields(event) {
    setTimeout(() => {

      this.el.nativeElement.value = this.el.nativeElement.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z ]/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '');
      event.preventDefault();

    }, 100)
  }

}
```

like `<input  specialIsAlphaNumeric placeholder="my love" value="Mam">`
don't forget add the Directive class in **declarations** on ngModule

Comment: How can i use another directive for currency xx.xxx,xx? i opened another questions for this? Can you please help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56930936/how-to-enter-only-a-number-like-this-xx-xxx-xx-currencyin-the-input-while-im-t

Comment: Do you need it while typing?

Comment: Yes, while typing.

Answer (score 2):

Now `newVal` isn't in any way connected to your input element. Try binding it using, for example, `ngModel`:

```
inputModel: string;

removeSpecialCharacters(event) {
    this.inputModel = event.target.value.replace('[^A-Za-z0-9]', '');
}
```

```
<input maxlength="10" (keydown)="this.removeSpecialCharacters($event)" [(ngModel)]="inputModel">
```

Answer (score 1):

use data binding and (change) event listener. if you're going for a `form` then consider using `formbuilder` and using `formControlName` for data bindig. that's an easier approach.